# Dynamically set pretty tick breaks and labels to include limits of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set pretty breaks and limits on a y scale when using `facet_wrap`. By "pretty" I mean that that the y scale should include all data. As you see in the image below (horizontal red lines), there should be a tick and a label in the horizontal red lines (some facets are ok but others not).

[image]

Another example:

[image]

I know how to set it for one simple plot, but this is more difficult when using facet_wrap in order to make it dynamic (not manual).

Reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(mes = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", 
"Ago", "Set", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"), class = "factor"), nombre_estacion = c("B", 
"A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A"
), parametro = c("Aluminio total mg/L", "Aluminio total mg/L", 
"Aluminio total mg/L", "Aluminio total mg/L", "Aluminio total mg/L", 
"Arsénico total mg/L", "Arsénico total mg/L", "Arsénico total mg/L", 
"Arsénico total mg/L", "Arsénico total mg/L", "Boro total mg/L", 
"Boro total mg/L", "Boro total mg/L", "Boro total mg/L", "Boro total mg/L", 
"Cadmio total mg/L", "Cadmio total mg/L", "Cadmio total mg/L", 
"Cadmio total mg/L", "Cadmio total mg/L", "Cobalto total mg/L", 
"Cobalto total mg/L", "Cobalto total mg/L", "Cobalto total mg/L", 
"Cobalto total mg/L", "Cobre total mg/L", "Cobre total mg/L", 
"Cobre total mg/L", "Cobre total mg/L", "Cobre total mg/L", "Hierro total mg/L", 
"Hierro total mg/L", "Hierro total mg/L", "Hierro total mg/L", 
"Hierro total mg/L", "Manganeso total mg/L", "Manganeso total mg/L", 
"Manganeso total mg/L", "Manganeso total mg/L", "Manganeso total mg/L"
), promedio_mensual = c(0.473, 37.55, 0.485, 1.216, 29.23, 0.13219, 
0.19974, 0.004585, 0.1123, 0.1709, 0.2466, 1.742, 0.16135, 0.258, 
1.455, 1.5e-05, 0.01849, 1.5e-05, 1.5e-05, 0.00993, 0.000215, 
0.11407, 0.00086, 5e-04, 0.0689, 0.00338, 2.149, 0.0018, 0.006, 
1.411, 1.0945, 54.82, 0.8717, 1.882, 52.25, 0.057905, 2.077, 
0.086905, 0.1082, 1.237), caudal_q75 = c(402.903225806452, 1772.65322580645, 
3556.27419354839, 651.892857142857, 3983.91071428571, 402.903225806452, 
1772.65322580645, 3556.27419354839, 651.892857142857, 3983.91071428571, 
402.903225806452, 1772.65322580645, 3556.27419354839, 651.892857142857, 
3983.91071428571, 402.903225806452, 1772.65322580645, 3556.27419354839, 
651.892857142857, 3983.91071428571, 402.903225806452, 1772.65322580645, 
3556.27419354839, 651.892857142857, 3983.91071428571, 402.903225806452, 
1772.65322580645, 3556.27419354839, 651.892857142857, 3983.91071428571, 
402.903225806452, 1772.65322580645, 3556.27419354839, 651.892857142857, 
3983.91071428571, 402.903225806452, 1772.65322580645, 3556.27419354839, 
651.892857142857, 3983.91071428571), carga_q75 = c(190.573225806452, 
66563.1286290322, 1724.79298387097, 792.701714285715, 116449.710178571, 
53.2597774193548, 354.069755322581, 16.3055171774194, 73.2075678571429, 
680.850341071428, 99.3559354838709, 3087.96191935484, 573.804841129032, 
168.188357142857, 5796.59008928571, 0.00604354838709677, 32.7763581451613, 
0.0533441129032258, 0.00977839285714286, 39.5602333928571, 0.0866241935483871, 
202.206553467742, 3.05839580645161, 0.325946428571429, 274.491448214286, 
1.36181290322581, 3809.43178225806, 6.4012935483871, 3.91135714285715, 
5621.29801785714, 440.977580645161, 97176.8498387097, 3100.00421451613, 
1226.86235714286, 208159.334821429, 23.3301112903226, 3681.80075, 
309.058008790323, 70.5348071428572, 4928.09755357143)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Plot:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(mes, carga_q75, fill = nombre_estacion)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~parametro, scales = "free_y", nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `limits` argument to a function that you can use to dynamically set the limits. In conjunction with the `scales::extended_breaks()` function factory, you can the limits to an appropriate break.

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(mes, carga_q75, fill = nombre_estacion)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = function(x) {
      brks <- scales::extended_breaks()(x)
      if (x[2] > max(brks)) {
        x <- c(x[1], max(brks) + diff(brks)[1:2])
      } else {
        x <- c(x[1], max(brks))
      }
      x
    },
    expand = c(0,0)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~parametro, scales = "free_y", nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Would you know how to make sure that breaks are integer? (without decimals)